# Difference between web::json::value::parse and web::json::value::string in Casablanca C++ REST SDK

Tags: c++, json, casablanca

I have a piece of code that looks like this (`obj` is a `web::json::value`):

```
try {
    obj[key_str] = web::json::value::parse(value_str);
}
catch (...) {
    obj[key_str] = web::json::value::string(value_str);
}
```

I am not able to find the difference between the two because for any input `value_str` that I give, such as the string `"value1"`, only the statement inside the `catch` runs.

So my question is - what is the **exact difference** between `::string()` and `::parse()`?

Could you show me a minimal example that demonstrates this difference? I am not able to differentiate between these two functions from the documentation alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*parse* takes a string and forms a **json object** out of it:

```
{"id": 1,"title": "test" }
```

Will give you an object of size 2, containing id = 1, and title = "test".

*string* takes a string and forms a **json string** out of it.

The later example will return à json string containing `"id": 1,"title": "test"`.
This basically means that you are trying to parse a json string which is not recognized as a json object. That will be the case with the example your are giving.

```
parse(const std::string& s)  { 
   std::cout << json.parse(s) << std::endl;
   std::cout << json.parse(s).size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << json.parse(s).type() << std::endl;
   std::cout << json.string(s) << std::endl;
   std::cout << json.string(s).size() << std::endl;
   std::cout << json.string(s).type() << std::endl;             
}
```

For `{"id": 1,"title": "test" }` return :

```
{"body":"body test","id":1,"title":"test","userId":1}
4
3
"{\"userId\":1, \"id\": 1,\"title\": \"test\",\"body\": \"body test\"}"
0
2
```

Notice the size of the json object and the fact the json string is between quotation and of size 0 instead of 4. Take a look at the type 3 (object) and 2 string.

For "value 1", which is not a json, it is a string, you will have:

```
"value 1"
0
"\"value 1\""
0
```

Notice here the 2 objects are of size 0, and type 2 (string). 
This is the value of the type:

```
enum value_type
        {
            /// Number value
            Number,
            /// Boolean value
            Boolean,
            /// String value
            String,
            /// Object value
            Object,
            /// Array value
            Array,
            /// Null value
            Null
        };
```

Comment: Thank you for the simple explanation and examples!